# Set Simplification

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, set, compression

Say I have two sets, `set1 = {a,b,c,d,e,f}` and `set2 = {a,b,c,d,e,g}`. Rather than expressing these explicitly, I want to create something like

```
common = {a,b,c,d,e}
set1 = common + f
set2 = common + g
```

If we wanted to represent `{a,b,c,h}`, we could represent it as `common - d - e + h`.

My goal is basically to be able to generate the optimal common portion to be used. With only one common section this isn't too challenging, but I need to allow more than one (but not unlimited, or the benefits gained would be trivial).

By optimal, I mean "least number of elements expressed". So in the above example, it "costs" 5 (number of elements) to make the `common` variable. Then sets 1 and 2 both cost 2 (one to reference common, one to add the extra element), totalling 7. Without the substitution, these would cost 12 to store (6 elements each). Similarly, in subtracting an element from a referenced would "cost" 1.

Another example,
`{a,b,c,d}, {a,c,d,e}, {e,f,g,h} and {e,f}`

could be

```
common1 = {a,c,d}
common2 = {e,f,g}
set1 = common1 + b
set2 = common1 + e
set3 = common2 + h
set4 = common2 - g
```

By allowing multiple common portions this becomes a lot more challenging. Is there a name for this type of problem, or something similar? It seems like it could be related to compression, but I haven't been able to find too many resources on where to start with this.

Some other details that may be relevent:

- Being allowed to reference multiple common portions to represent one set can be valid, but isn't required.
- For my use case, the sets will typically be around 20 elements and around 10 different sets.

Comment: Possibly related: [formal concept analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_concept_analysis).

Comment: Can an element be in multiple common sets? E.g. common1 = {a,b,c,d}; common2 = {d,e,f,g}; set1 = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g} = common1 + common2 - d.

Comment: Yeah, no issues with being in common sets. - do would not even be specified as it is a set not a list so duplicates are ignored

Answer (score 2):

You could find all atomic sets, that is all sets that are never not seen apart.

```
{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}       | {a,b,c,d} = {a,b,c,d},{e,f,g,h} 
{a,b,c,d},{e,f,g,h}     | {a,c,d,e} = {a,b,c,d},{e,f,g,h} 
{a,c,d},{b},{e},{f,g,h} | {e,f,g,h} = {a,c,d},{b},{e},{f,g,h}
{a,c,d},{b},{e},{f,g,h} | {e,f}     = {a,c,d},{b},{e},{f},{g,h}

{a,b,c,d} = {a,c,d},{b}
{a,c,d,e} = {a,c,d},{e}
{e,f,g,h} = {e},{f},{g,h}
{e,f}     = {e},{f}
```

This is a little closer but it doesnt solve the minimal breakdown.

I dont think you can find the minimal because i suspect that it is NP-Hard.  If you consider a set S and create a graph where each possible subset of S is a node G. Now give a node weight according to the length of the subset, and draw an edge between each node that corresponds to the amount of change. {abc} -> {a} has a weight of 2. {bcd} -> {abe} has a weight of 4. Now to find a minimal solution to the common set problem you need to find a minimal weight spanning tree that covers each of the sets you are interested in. If you find that you can use this to build a minimal common set -- these would be equivelent. Finding minimum weight tree in a node weighted graph is called the Node-Weighed Steiner Tree Problem.  A Node weighted Steiner Tree Problem can be shown equivalent to the Steiner Tree Problem. The Steiner Tree problem can be show to be NP-Hard. So I strongly suspect the problem you are trying to solve is NP-Hard.

http://theory.cs.uni-bonn.de/info5/steinerkompendium/node15.html

http://theory.cs.uni-bonn.de/info5/steinerkompendium/node17.html

Comment: I don't think your argument shows this problem is NP-hard; it just shows that solving an NP-hard problem lets you solve this problem, too. There's lots of structure in the graph in question that isn't required by the Steiner problem, so it isn't obvious (to me, at least) that a more specialized algorithm could do better than one that had to solve all instances of the Steiner problem.